# HOw to Design Middleware for filter data between application and database in Asp.net core 6

Tags: asp.net, filter, middleware, asp.net-core-6.0

When the user sends a request, various queries are executed inside the program to finally answer his request.
I want to set limits for the information received by users through a filter in the query sent to the database.
For example, the query that the program sends to the database under normal conditions is as follows:

```
(from m in _context.City
select m).ToList()
```

But I change it to this mode according to the user's name and profile :
at first, we identify the user and her role, and then change the query

```
(from m in _context.City
where m.Province == 12
select m).ToList()
```

I defined a middleware that I introduced in the program file as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new RequestResponseActionFilter());
})
```

But this middleware does not do what was said

Comment: ActionFilter is a filter used to execute custom logic before and after executing controller actions,Authorize filter is a filter used to declaratively specify access requirements. It is used to restrict controller or action method level to specify roles, policies or other authorizations.If you want to change the database query statement based on user information, you can try adding conditional statements directly to your method to modify the query statement based on the results.

Comment: Yes, what you said is completely correct, but it is not the answer to my question. My question is that when there is a linq expression in the program, it sends a request to the database. How, where and with what filter can I see the text of that request and if needed Let me change, for example, you can use SQL Profiler to see the same requests without being able to change them, but I want to see it in the asp.net core 6 project and change it if necessary before sending it.

Comment: Do you want is this filter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters which like this form:
`modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasQueryFilter(m => user.UserName != null && user.UserRole == "Admin" ? m.Province == 12 : false);` ?